# Chrome does not come to foreground after clicking link in other app

Tags: google-chrome, kde, plasma

When I click on a link for example in a mail in Thunderbird or a message in Slack, an already running chrome opens a new tab and opens the page there, but does not come to the foreground. I have to manually click on the chrome icon in the taskbar to see the chrome window. Is there a way to change that so that on opening the URL chrome goes into the foreground automatically? I think this should work this way per default but for some reason doesn't on my (freshly installed) machine.

I am on Ubuntu 20, with KDE Plasma, Chrome 97.

Comment: DO you have the same problem with other browsers ( like firefox)? I think it is related to KDE settings, I use ubuntu since 14.04 and never experienced this as I use default gnome/unity.

Comment: To test this I switched to Firefox as default browser and it worked. Afterwards I switched back to Chrome and the problem was gone! Amazing :) Thank you. If you want the upvote you can write an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the poster's comment, it looks like a kind of miss-configuration related to KDE/chrome, but here is a shortcut to resolve the problem.

Install [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) and set it as the default browser. Then switch back to Google Chrome!